# How to double click unfold group in Xcode

Tags: xcode

=======

`Update 2017 April 9th:`

Apple just updated Xcode to version 8.3.2. BUG FIXED! Enjoy coding!

`Update 2017 April 9th:`

Apple just updated Xcode to version 8.3.1. Didn't fix this bug yet.

`Update 2017 April 4th:`

Thanks to @Aamir for sending a bug report. Let's wait for the response.

`Update 2017 March 31st:`

This bug appears in newest version of Xcode 8.3.

=======

I got a new Mac today. In old time I double click a group in the left tree view, the groups expand.

[image]

[image]

In my new Mac it opens a new window. Any one know where to config this?

[image]

Comment: restart you mac

Comment: Did you old Mac have the same version of macOS and Xcode as you new Mac? I get a new window too. Never tried double-clicking on a folder before in Xcode. Seems normal to me.

Comment: @RichardG It didn't work..

Comment: @rmaddy I thought they were same. But I checked the about window and was surprised to find that the Xcode on old Mac haven't updated automatically yet. The older one is 8.2.1 and the newer one is 8.3.

Comment: @ManuQiao did you find out how to fold/unfold group on double click? It drives me crazy :/

Comment: @Rendel No, bro. Yeah this drives me crazy too. Once I figure it out I will post solution here at first minute.

Comment: @Rendel I found that if you add folder into the project instead of group remains the old behavior. If you are starting a new project... Somehow this could be a solution.

Comment: @Rendel No, this cannot be the solution. You can only add empty file in folder using command+N.

Comment: @ManuQiao yeah, and you cannot turn pods, frameworks, products and other xcode generated groups into folder references :(

Comment: Driving me nuts, everytime I double click a folder, instead of expand/collapse, it opens a new window, lame! just submitted a bug report

Comment: Guys, apple just released Xcode version 8.3.2, bug fixed! @Rendel

Comment: Guys, apple just released Xcode version 8.3.2, bug fixed! @Aamir